# Restricting access to website, allowing only a single IP access

Tags: apache, .htaccess

For testing purposes, I set this in my htacces:

```
order deny, allow
deny from all
allow from 123.456.789.000
```

But Firefox shows:

> Internal Server Error The server
>   encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to
>   complete your request.

Error log shows:

> [Thu Feb 24 04:05:12 2011] [alert]
>   [client 123.456.789.000]
>   /var/www/vhosts/website.org/httpdocs/.htaccess:
>   order takes one argument,
>   'allow,deny', 'deny,allow', or
>   'mutual-failure'

What does this mean? What am i doing wrong?
Thanks for helping with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space in your `Order` directive argument.